# Why is to_zarr requesting memory for a 4d array when the variable is only 3d?

Tags: python-xarray

I am trying to write out a 3d array to a zarr store. Should be straightforward but the `to_zarr` step is failing with an error message indicating it is trying to write out a 4d array and running out of memory. The 3d array is obtained from a 4d array using `isel` and slicing out the values for a single value along the fourth dimension, such that the result is a 3d array. See the attached image showing the field I am trying to write out after the `isel` operation.

[image: 3d array I am trying to write to a zarr store]

I then ran the following commands:

```
ds_sst = sst.chunk('auto').to_dataset(name='sst')
ds_sst.to_zarr('./test.zarr',mode='w')
```

Here is the error message I am getting:
`MemoryError: Unable to allocate 354. GiB for an array with shape (5928, 50, 489, 655) and data type float32`

The weird part is the fourth dimension which should have been squeezed out in the original array after the `isel` operation has a length of 50. If you look at the error message, it suggests the `isel` operation did nothing? Yet the image shows the field is indeed 3d with a size ~11 Gb. So I am puzzled why the `to_zarr` operation needs 354 Gb of memory.